# I copied a navbar code from official bootstrap website v4.0, The code is same but the output is different why so?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I copied a navbar code from official bootstrap website v4.0, The code is same but the output is different why so?[Screenshot of both output attached below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGqwo.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you need to include the relevant code in your question so that we can see what might be causing the problem and be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forget to import the [Bootstrap library](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/).

Add this code in your `<head>`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: @AmitDutta no problem please don't forget to`validate` my answer thanks